# React Hook returning base values in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I ran into a roadblock when trying to update a hook when the web socket is called with new information and noticed that the hooks are returning the default values I set them to inside my useEffect, whilst inside the render it is returning the correct values. I am completely stumped and unsure why and was curious as to if anyone could help, much appreciated.

```
const [view, setView] = useState(false)
const [curFlip, setFlip] = useState(null)

tradeSocket.addEventListener('message', async (msg) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(msg.data)
      if (message.tradelink) {
        // not needed
      } else if (message.redItems || message.blueItems) {
        // not needed
      } else if (message.flips) {
        console.log('effect ', view, curFlip) // this is where the issue occurs, it returns false and null
        if (view && curFlip) {
          console.log('theyre viewing a flip')
          for (let i = 0; i < message.flips.length; i++) {
            console.log('looping ' + i, message.flips[i].offer)
            if (message.flips[i].offer === curFlip.offer) {
              setFlip(message.flips[i])
            }
          }
        }

        setCoinflips(message.flips)
      } else if (message.tradeid) {
        // not needed
      }
    })
```

[Image of what values it returns per render / effect called.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSRnu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our output, it seems that you set up the socket listener only once on initial render in useEffect.

Now since the useEffect callback is run once, the values used from closure inside the listener function will always show the initial valued

The solution here is to add view and curFlip to dependency array of useEffect and close the socket in useEffect cleanup function

```
useEffect(() => {
  tradeSocket.addEventListener('message', async (msg) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(msg.data)
      if (message.tradelink) {
        // not needed
      } else if (message.redItems || message.blueItems) {
        // not needed
      } else if (message.flips) {
        console.log('effect ', view, curFlip) // this is where the issue occurs, it returns false and null
        if (view && curFlip) {
          console.log('theyre viewing a flip')
          for (let i = 0; i < message.flips.length; i++) {
            console.log('looping ' + i, message.flips[i].offer)
            if (message.flips[i].offer === curFlip.offer) {
              setFlip(message.flips[i])
            }
          }
        }

        setCoinflips(message.flips)
      } else if (message.tradeid) {
        // not needed
      }
    })
    return () => {
        tradeSocket.close();
    }
 }
}, [curFlip, view]);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I really appreciate the thorough explanation as to why it didn't work and how to fix it.